# PHPMailer - Print all files uploaded

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using the PHPMailer to send e-mails like a notice that new files has been uploaded. The PHPMailer looks like this to create the HTML e-mails:

```
$mail->Body    = 'Hi!<br/>'
. '<br/>These files has been uploaded:<br/><br/>'
. '<b> ' . for($i = 0; $i < count($data['data']['metas']); $i++){$file = $data['data']['metas'][$i]["name"]; echo $file <br />;} . '<br/>'
```

This doesn't work at all, and I somehow understand why. However, I can't figure out to send in plain text in the e-mail what files that has been uploaded.

This code alone in PHP works perfectly, but not in the HTML e-mail sent from PHPMailer.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($data['data']['metas']); $i++){$file = $data['data']['metas'][$i]["name"]; echo $file <br />;}
```

Any ideas how to solve this, so I can send a e-mail with all files uploaded?

Comment: You misunderstand how `echo` works

Comment: $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');

Comment: @MrDarkLynx I'm trying to print all the filenames uploaded in my mail.

Comment: @Breakermind I'm not adding attachments to my e-mail. I'm trying to print all the files uploaded from my form in plain text in my HTML e-mail.

Comment: You have to append each file to the body in a foor loop. Have a look at Milli's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are forming your `$mail->Body` string. Try the following;

```
$mail->Body = 'Hi!<br/><br/>These files has been uploaded:<br/><br/>';
for($i = 0; $i < count($data['data']['metas']); $i++) {
    $mail->Body .= $data['data']['metas'][$i]["name"] . '</br>';
}
```

Comment: Great tip! That did it for me and works perfectly. Thanks for the help! This was exactly what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

How send files with email:

```
    require_once '../class.phpmailer.php';
error_reporting(E_ERROR & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);     
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

try {
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
  // Add files
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

Comment: Not looking for sending attachments, just printing all the filenames uploaded in plain text in my e-mail.